# Unable to boot elementary OS after new important security and hardware support update

Tags: release-freya, boot, updates, security

[image]
I have installed above update and after that system cannot boot. it displayed the "e" logo and after that everything goes black again, does anyone know how to fix this? already tried recovery mode. nothing happened. 
Thanks
os: elementary OS freya

Comment: What hardware are you running? Do you get any error messages, or just a black screen? Thanks!

Comment: HP ProBook 4540s (corei7) - 8GB ram, Radeon graphics. did you get the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have to do a fresh install.  don't know what will happen when i  upgrade to the Loki. I know this is not the best solution. but i mark this as "accepted". if anyone know how to ignore unsupported updates feel free to comment below. it maybe a proactive solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Ubuntu switched to an open-source Nvidia driver, which causes problems for some people.

You may be able to solve the problem by booting into recovery mode and installing the proprietary Nvidia drivers.

To start, we'll boot into recovery mode, enable networking, and get to a terminal prompt:

1. Restart your computer. If you dual boot, grub will appear. Otherwise, hold shift while your computer boots to open grub.
2. From the options that appear in grub, choose recovery mode. The recovery mode option will look something like this: `elementary OS, with Linux [version details] (Recovery mode)`.
3. The system will boot into recovery mode. After a few moments, the recovery mode menu will appear.
4. Choose "enable networking". Answer "yes" at the dialog that appears.
5. Choose "drop to root shell prompt".

At this point, you should have a text prompt where you can download and install the driver.

Next, we'll install the Nvidia drivers. I don't have an Nvidia chip on my computer, so I've copied the following steps from [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics).

1. Run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`
2. Run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and then `sudo apt-get update`.
3. Run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-364`.
4. Reboot.

Comment: Can you tell me how to enable terminal in recovery mode? every time i enter in to the recovery mode it end up with normal boot. Thanks

Comment: I'm not affected by this, but... *really?!* An Ubuntu *security* update just switches your drivers?! I can't believe that, it would be *that* much irresponsible. I had spent *nights* on getting the NVIDIA graphics drivers up & running on my girlfriend's laptop with EOS Freya... @Praveen: Not sure about recovery mode, but a `chroot` should work easily. Google should give you an easy-to-follow guideline for Ubuntu (which should be compatible), depending on your language of preference.

Comment: @Praveen, I've updated the answer with details on how to get into recovery mode and get to a terminal. Does that help?

Comment: @RyanDeBeasi Thank you very much for help. i have installed nvidia drives as you mentioned, but it didn't work. maybe do i need to install radeon graphics ?

Comment: @theV0ID Thanks for the comment? by chroot mode can i recover ? (i'm new to Linux ).

Comment: @Praveen, does installing `nvidia-367` instead of `nvidia-364` help? Apparently that's the latest stable version.

Comment: Also, you could try rolling back to a previous version of the kernel as described here: http://askubuntu.com/a/738742/486628

Comment: @RyanDeBeasi really appreciate your help. unfortunately none of them work for me. is it possible to recover system from live usb?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44437/discussion-between-ryan-debeasi-and-praveen).

Comment: Finally did a fresh install, thanks for the help guys

Comment: Glad to hear it - you're very welcome! Feel free to add that as an answer and mark it as "accepted" so that this question can be resolved. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

OK. I can confirm the other answer is actually working.

with one exception.

I wasn't able to start my grub, but I was able to ctrl + alt + F1 into my terminal, where I have fully running Freya, just without a front end.

*NOTE* This is only a solution if you previously installed proprietary NVidia driver, and you will need to use your Nvidia installer to recover.

to get your front end, steps are:

1. wait until your screen is blacked out, hit ctrl+alt+F1 into terminal.
2. in terminal check if you can turn off you x server by:

> service lightdm stop

if it says unknown instance, then you ignore it for the moment.

3. now get your Nvidia installer to do the following:

> ~$: ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.45.11.run --uninstall

*NOTE* if you did what Ryan (the other answer) said, using apt-get purge to remove it, you will still need to do this step.

4. now restart and boot into terminal again.
5. now run:

> ~$: chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.45.11.run
>
> ~$: sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.45.11.run

6. follow the instruction to complete NVIDIA installation.
7. once complete you can run:

> ~$: service lightdm start

you should now see your GUI back.